# How to custom assign link to wordpress admin bar logout

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to assign conditional link to the Wordpress top admin bar "Logout". In which file i can put condition for that. Actually, I am creating membership login portal. For that i need to assign the not admin user to the different login page instead **wp-login.php** Page. For Example:

```
<?php if(user == 'admin'): ?>
<a href="http://mysite/wp-login.php">Logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="http://mysite/members.php">Logout</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Any help will be appretiated.!!

Comment: do you want to Redirect user after logout?

Comment: not like that. i want to redirect according to the user role.

Comment: Try <?php if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
       // to something
 } ?>

Comment: @junkk rr: was my answer helpful?

Comment: Raunak i had used the custom coding in wp-admin folder file. Thanx for your time to reply.

Comment: Raunak i had used the custom coding in wp-admin folder file. Thanx for your time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code,

```
/**
* Sets the custom cookie with the redirect URL
*/
function wh_set_logout_url_cookie() {

    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) return false;

    global $current_user;
    //getting current user role
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    $exists = $_COOKIE['the_logout_url'];

    if( empty( $exists ) ) {
        switch ($user_role) {
            case 'administrator':
                $expire = time() + ( 86400 * 7); 
                @setcookie('the_logout_url', 'your-url', $expire);
                break;
            case 'editor':
                $expire = time() + ( 86400 * 7); 
                @setcookie('the_logout_url', 'your-url', $expire);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wh_set_logout_url_cookie');

/**
 * Applies the URL saved in the cookie to the wp_logout_url for redirect
*/
function wh_logout_redirect_url( $logouturl ) {

    $redirect = $_COOKIE['the_logout_url']; 

    if( $redirect ) //redirect to the custom set url
        return $logouturl . '&amp;redirect_to=' . urlencode( $redirect );

    //redirect to homepage
    return $logouturl . '&amp;redirect_to=' . urlencode( get_option( 'siteurl' ) );

}
add_filter('logout_url', 'wh_logout_redirect_url', 10, 2);
```

replace `your-url` with your custom url.